# Choosing a Programming Language Systematically

Tags: programming-languages, web-development, web-applications

I am looking for a methodology for choosing a language. I am not asking for opinions about languages.  I have been tasked with the process of comparing our shop's current language with others that are available. We are a web development shop btw.

Our CEO would like a full white paper about all web based languages that are available, What parent language they are derivatives of (e.g jsp is from java which is from c/c++). I need to create a matrix with all the key factors of a particular language as well and the short comings of that given language.  Is the language limited by platform, is it designed for functional programming, procedural or OO or can it be used with any programming paradigm?

I also need to have information less technical, like the size of the talent pool for a given language and the median salary in that pool. How will the marketplace view our choice?

We started looking for a consultant to help us understand all of these things but what we have found it that most consultants are coming from a development background and often it seems that the answer is "*xxx* is the best language because it is the one that I have used the most over the last *n* years and it has never let me down. You could Supplement it with *yyy* for front end and use *zzz* library"

I am feeling overwhelmed with this task and I feel like the best course of action, given what our CEO is looking for, is to look in the world of academia and hire a professor with no actual development experience to come in and "teach" us about all possible languages.

Has anyone else had to go through this exercise? If you have can you share the steps and/or methodology you used to go through the process?

Comment: Does the CEO actually plan to use this matrix to decide things such as "We will use ${language} to build ${nextBigProject}!" To build something that might actually be useful for this (though I'm not sure it will ever be *seriously* useful) would probably take a significant amount of time, and there would be ongoing maintenance on it as well.

Comment: I think a general guide to choose a language/environment for a project might be to *first* try to get a deeper understanding of the specific problem that the project is trying to solve (in a language-agnostic way), look for tools/libraries that best help solve it *at that time*, then look at what languages you need to know to work with those tools/libraries. That will probably give you shortlist of languages, and from there you can winnow it down based on your familiarity with them, vendor support, budget, etc...

Comment: The *very first* question to answer is, "do we need to change at all?"  What problems are not being solved by your current choice of language?

Comment: [How can Stack Overflow help developers evaluate technologies?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145813/165773) _"This morning I had about 8 frameworks in front of me, trying to decide which one I'll use..."_

Comment: How does platform fit into the picture? JVM, CLR [Mono or .NET], Node, bare metal? And that backs out into Operating Systems and Open Source versus proprietary tools in one direction and SQL versus NoSQL in another. And of course preferred IDE's and other parts of the toolchain (C# in Eclipse? probably not). The task looks impossible because the question isn't the right one.

Comment: In practice you might as well throw darts.  In the web arena (especially JavaScript, et al) there are dozens (if not hundreds) of options, with assorted strengths, weaknesses, affinities, and incompatibilities.  You can analyze it to death, or just make an educated guess, go forward, and do a mid-course correction if needed.

Comment: Instead of choosing a language, maybe it would be better to look at it from the product's perspective. How much it would cost to develop, sell and maintain  product X using technology T. You will be able to identify pro's and con's easier. Looking at just a language is like looking at different tools in a toolbox and wondering which one should you pick for a voyage to another planet :) You just don't know what you will face.

Comment: Java is *not* derivative of C nor C++, although that irrelevant fraction of the base syntax which newbies start from or that is taught in school looks similar (but it is not). C and C++ are different languages with different strengths and weaknesses and the choice between either is subject of heated debate. There is no such thing as "a prof that will teach about all possible languages". While the task you have been given is inherently flawed, these naive assumptions denote anyway lack of sufficient background in the one who wrote this question.

Comment: Note that the most important, and thus important factor is knowlege of a language.  Even if (for example) C++ was slightly more suited to solving a problem than Java, if 'everyone' in your organisation knows Java (and not C++), and Java is capable of producing a solution that meets requirements, getting everyone to change language, learn said language, and then maintain code written in a new language will be A) far slower than implementing it in a known language, B) Far more expensive.  This is one of those times where you should 'stick to what you know' if possible.

Comment: @Baldrickk: Java is *heavily* based on Objective-C and gets pretty much nothing from C++. Most of what is different between Java and C++ is inherited from Smalltalk and was decided long before C++ even existed.

Comment: @JörgWMittag ok, In that case I stand corrected. I have to say that I've only heard this third-hand and not actually looked into it myself.

Comment: @Baldrickk: Here's your first-hand source: http://www.cs.gmu.edu/~sean/stuff/java-objc.html (well, actually, it's a re-print of a first-hand source, but the *actual* first-hand source should be discoverable from there, provided it hasn't been lost to bitrot).

Comment: @ignis That depends how you define "derivative". Practically every language is related to other languages these days. Just look at the Wikipedia sidebar for any programming language and note the lengthy *"Influenced by"* list. But you are absolutely right that even asking this question shows that the CEO isn't qualified to be making these decisions. Any kind of "derivative" information is only useful for historical curiosity; it should not have anything at all to do with choosing a language.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's input on this.  The comment "these naive assumptions denote anyway lack of sufficient background in the one who wrote this question." Is very true.  I completely have insufficient background to write this doc and that is why I came here (and I am very glad I did) I have been a practitioner for the past 20 yrs and although I think I know what path we should take and why I am having a difficult time writing the supporting case for that as I am unable to compare and contrast all web languages which is what is wanted by our CEO. Thanks again for the continued discussion.

Comment: @nmclean It is not my intention to sound arrogant, but it smells like my comment above also applies to you. 1. per the dictionary, and given the context of this question, "influenced by" and "derivative" are not interchangeable or even comparable. I don't understand the practical purpose of your reply. 2. your argument is based on the false assumption that Wikipedia is or aims to be a reliable source, especially for pages crowded by newbies.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490

Comment: @nmclean I encourage you (and everyone) to read the enlightening "first-hand source" posted above by Jorg W Mittag, it is a good read.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17756/discussion-on-question-by-lance-choosing-a-programming-language-systematically) .

Comment: @ignis I was mainly supporting your point. The bit about "derivatives" was an aside. I'm rather tired of people halting discussion via conveniently dismissing Wikipedia when a) it has long been shown to be comparably accurate and b) the same people happily accept other search results with remarkably fewer citations. I digress: I truly don't understand why you're being so defensive, and exaggerating the subtle difference between "influence" and "derivative". What I find most baffling is that the very article you refer to in your next comment literally uses both words interchangeably itself.

Comment: Why doesn't the CEO let the tech people make tech decisions?

Answer (score 53):

@FrustratedWithFormsDesigner hinted at this above, I'll be more blunt: you've been charged with a expensive but useless task.

I suspect the CEO is looking for irrefutable, objective evidence which will support his choice of language. The problem is that preference of language is loaded with far too many subjective and extrinsic factors for the white-paper to be meaningful let alone useful.

Put another way, if there were an ideal language, everyone would be using it instead of those "objectively" defective languages. It also bespeaks a degree of micromanagement that ought be the province of the engineers who will have to make it work. Erlang might be the "objectively best" but if no one knows it, add a 6 month/engineer start up cost and 6 more  month / engineer to gain competency.

Since I don't have your job, I'm not worried about losing it, although you may. I'd give the CEO a paper on the Physical Church-Turing Thesis. I'd then get together with the senior engineers and get their non-rigorous, non-objective opinion as to what should be used and tell the CEO that's what you shall use. In exchange you'll promise the engineers will keep out of board meetings, CFOs, Accountancy Methods, selection of VPs and so on. There is a reason we specialize, and he has no more place in engineering preferences than you do in his domain.

Comment: Ha, I love the reckless enthusiasm of the last paragraph. I would say it is the CEOs domain because of that pesky 6 months you mentioned, which is all you need to tell him/her imho.

Comment: I was kind of glib in the last paragraph: this requires political diplomacy on a high level. Make sure your colleagues share your point of view **first** and then use (or learn) the maneuver you need. Go gentle, sell him down the path step-by-step. Have your fellows catch him in hallway chats to support your points. But do be up front: "I don't think I can produce the white-paper you want because of…". If he won't back off this fail-from-the-start march, start sending out resumes.

Comment: "Physical Church-Turing Thesis" Let's not go there. Very few programming languages have a formal semantics, pretty much a prerequisite for it to be Turing complete. (Without one, it isn't even a model of computation.)

Comment: @Rhymoid Aye. I was expecting the CEO to accept the naive view of the meaning of PCTT if he even bothered. An inside joke among the CS heavy engineers, perhaps?

Comment: Just choose Lisp and be done with it.

Comment: By Lisp, you mean ClojureScript of course.  :-)

Comment: Regardless of it's usefulness or lack thereof, I have been tasked to "evaluate all languages" before we move forward on any initiatives in our engineering department. So whether I agree with your assesment or not, the quest continues.  I DO however apprieciate your input and it will be included in my end product. Thanks @msw

Comment: +1. It's your job as an engineer to convey to a CEO why this is *not* a good approach. This may be hard because it kind of looks like a good approach, but it's necessary.

Comment: i.e. if you do the spreadsheet approach you're likely to pick a ridiculous language with high marks because the actually important factors you intuited as a matter of judgment but did not weight properly on paper. This is not only useless, it's dangerous!

Answer (score 25):

Some broad brush strokes to consider:

#### Language popularity

This really shouldn't matter, because popularity does not necessarily equate with productivity, expressiveness or any of the other language qualities that matter more, but this consideration often trumps all other considerations because:

1. It's easier to find software developers in a popular language.
2. It's easier to find tools and libraries in a popular language.
3. Decision makers don't understand language tradeoffs, so they'll make the safe decision ("many companies use this language, so it must be good").

#### Applicability to the problem domain

Any program can be written in any Turing-complete programming language, but some languages are better suited for certain problem domains than others.  If you're writing web applications, you probably will gravitate to languages and tools that are well-suited for that, and they most likely will be object-oriented languages.

On the other hand, if you're going to be writing software that's primarily research-based or math-based, you will probably gravitate towards languages that embrace *functional* paradigms.

And, of course, there's everything in between.  Many languages support multiple paradigms, and some software patterns exist solely to overcome limitations in those languages that lack certain features or paradigms.

#### Expressiveness and productivity

Some languages are more expressive than others.  What can be written in one language using a thousand lines of code can be written in a more expressive language using a hundred lines of code.  The tradeoff is that the hundred lines of code is probably written in a less popular language, by people with greater expertise.

A lot of the lines of code present in object-oriented languages used to write line-of-business applications are ceremony.  This ceremony, while costing time and effort to develop, also provides a visible structure that wouldn't otherwise be readily apparent in a more expressive language.  It allows people with less expertise than they would otherwise need to work on the code with a reduced amount of risk.

#### The era of multiple languages

I'll conclude by asserting that the desire to decide on a single language may be a false dilemma.  Applications today are often written, not in one, but in many languages.  Each language has its own strengths, and (in theory) is specifically designed for the task it is being used.  Some problem domains (such as web browser logic or database access) require specific languages.

Comment: I would add to the last point that if you want to use multiple languages, it could be useful to consider a platform that supports easy interoperation between them (.Net CLR or JVM).

Comment: Really? The era of multiple languages? I have no interest in flipping between C#, F# and C++/CLI on the same day. Is the assumption we strictly the areas of code we edit, or that we are all become proficient in multiple languages? This isn't the place to discuss this, but just a heads up that that's a contentious brush stroke you've got there.

Comment: @NathanCooper: You mean you've never written a web application?  Even a small one?  Or had to port a mobile app to multiple platforms?  Or worked in embedded?  Or retrieved data from a SQL database?

Comment: @Robert Harvey, I built applications that run nearly everywhere (iOS, Android, PC, Mac, Browser, Linux, Servers and could, if desired run on xBox, PS3, some TV's etc.)  How many prgramming languages do I use?  1 - C#.

Comment: @NPSF3000: Naturally, you didn't bother to disclose your method of sorcery.  I call shenanigans.

Comment: @RobertHarvey.  It's publically available, I use the Unity game engine (powered by mono) for my mobile work (and most of the theoretical support) though occasionally we use Xamarin.  For desktop Unity works, though I'm also doing a project in WPF... again another C# friendly technology.  I also build custom and WCF servers in console apps and as services, which can run on Windows and Linux (thanks to mono).  For browser stuff, I've used Unity and am currently using Silverlight (sadly it's being depreciated) - and if I was into web dev I'd look into ASP MVC.  One language, many platforms.

Comment: @NPSF3000 While C# may be a good choice for what you do (though using Unity certainly stretches things a bit since it's explicitly designed for them to do all the multi-language heavy lifting for you), your one anecdote does not rebut the point. Certainly most non-trivial projects are multi-language in the sense that they use SQL and another technology, but even beyond that, many use different programming languages in parallel, or write their application in one language and their tools in another, etc. I do not find the assertion contentious at all.

Comment: @Chris Hayes, Sure it does, I'm not claiming you can't do it with multiple languages, just that utilizing multiple languages is not required decision (we keep to C# because it's what we need, not because we're against other languages).  Another trend along these lines is Javascript - which has client and server support.  I like how you mention SQL... I work with databases all the time and don't use a single line of it.

Comment: @NPSF3000 Clearly it's not *required*. No one is arguing that. The argument is that it can be beneficial, and that restricting yourself to a single language is not necessary. Your argument seems to be that it's never beneficial.

Comment: @ChrisHayes no my argument is that it is not beneficial by default.  Learning SQL so you can use a database is a considerable waste of time and resources.  Learning SQL because the best database for the job uses it, and the benefits outweigh the costs is a much smarter decision.  I believe this distinction was lost in Roberts answer, hence the comment.  For example I quote:  "Some problem domains (such as ... database access) require specific languages." This is false.

Comment: @NPSF3000 If that's your problem with it, then *say that*. Don't make us go through this rigmarole of trying to figure out what you mean. I'm sure Robert would be happy to make an edit if you had stated outright "I disagree that some problem domains require specific languages". That said, I see no implication at all here that working in multiple languages is "beneficial by default".

Comment: "This ceremony also provides a visible structure that wouldn't otherwise be readily apparent"... Wonderfully put! +1

Comment: @Robert Harvey Ahhh. Good point. I hadn't really counted a javascript, C#, SQL project as "multi-language" because it's minimal and all of it has purpose. I would say there's still a cetral point to what I said.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I was initially responding to Roberts comment: "@NathanCooper: You mean you've never written a web application? Even a small one? Or had to port a mobile app to multiple platforms? Or worked in embedded? Or retrieved data from a SQL database? "  Where I have done some of those things and not needed multiple languages.

Comment: Specifically on the last point, the same solution could easily need at least three or four platform-dependent languages just to barely run these days.  I could see where a lot of fairly simple data management programs could get by with C# and some version of SQL (that's two languages on its own), but add even the simplest of websites to such a program, and now you've got C#, SQL, HTML, probably CSS and JavaScript, and the list keeps on going for just the proof of concept.

Answer (score 5):

There are business reasons for choosing a language, and there are engineering reasons for choosing a language, and the twain do not always meet.  Throwing in academic reasons is likely to make things worse.  I doubt a professor will be able to help you in the way you need.

The facts about a language's ancestry and features are pretty easy to find.  You could probably spend a day on wikipedia to fill most of that out.  Talent pool size and salary are more difficult, because most people don't consider themselves single-language programmers.  Companies who use less popular languages like Scala pretty much expect to hire good general programmers who don't have language-specific experience.  Judging from some presentations I've seen, that strategy seems to have worked out well.

Even knowing the facts still leaves you with a pretty subjective choice.  Your CEO is going to want it boiled down to a rough metric something like dollars per feature.  To get an accurate picture, you're going to have to do some prototypes, then talk about how easy it was to learn, how fast it was to write a prototype once you learned the basics, how easy you think it would be to maintain, and how broadly applicable you think it would be to the kind of work you typically do.

Rather than trying to cover all languages, I would seek to get representatives from the different programming paradigms and types of frameworks, and implement a prototype in each.

Here's a rough list of back end categories:

- Microsoft. (May have subcategories.  I know nothing about them.)
- Heavyweight OOP, like Drupal.
- Lightweight OOP, like python bottle.
- Play/lift/scalatra using Scala.
- Play/lift using Java.
- Spring-like.
- Struts-like.
- Rails-like.
- Haskell-based.
- Node.js

On the front end:

- OOP-style JavaScript
- Functional-style JavaScript, like with Underscore
- Reactive-style JavaScript, like with Bacon
- Google Web Toolkit
- Elm

Spending a day or two on each category, implementing a simple prototype, would take you a couple months, after which you would have a much better idea of the strengths and weaknesses of each.  Perhaps you could rule some out more quickly based on your company's culture or experience.

Since this is a business report, I would also take some time googling things like "What language does <company> use," substituting various companies you admire.  Many of them have written whitepapers of their own on why they made specific language choices, which would make excellent references for you to include.

Answer (score 4):

Identify and cost the shortcomings inherent to your existing development process as $A. 
Identify the cost of switching to any other development process as $B.

If $A is less then $B, stop.

If your known shortcomings outweigh the cost of change (and that is a big if!) then analyse the shortcomings in detail and start looking for a language/development environment/development process changes that addresses them, one that wont introduce other more expensive problems.

To be honest, unless you are currently trying to develop web apps in Fortran, then the only impact the language you use will have is on the cost of contractors you use to fill the gaps. Main stream and mature languges/tools/development processes have already solved most of the problems you are likely to face where as the hottest, newest and sexiest tools come with the most expensive trainers and contractors, but the least mature solutions. And if you do have shortcomings that warrant such a change, it is unlikely that your choice of language will fully address them.

However, if profitability is not the primary objective here then you need to factor in the the stigma of being considered old-fashioned against the kudos of being cutting edge. Ask your boss for the dollar values to use for this part of the equation.